# Highlight jQuery function, and jQuery .toggle() functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have issue with that I've looked around the web for a highlight function attached to a search function. And I've found one and it works.

But my issue is that whenever I did a search, my .toggle() jQuery wouldn't work at all. I've tried to see for errors in console.log but nothing shows

I just want to point out that the toggle() function(s) do work when you don't use the search function and both jQuery scripts are in their own file.

I was asked to make a "Fiddle" so I did. 
https://jsfiddle.net/8puto9db/13/

But strangely enough it works here but not in my text editor/browser.

```js
$("#Searchfield").keydown(function(event) {
  if (event.which == 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var searchTextBox = $("#Searchfield");
    searchTextBox.val(searchTextBox.val().replace(/(\s+)/, "(<[^>]+>)*$1(<[^>]+>)*"));
    var TextArea = $(".Mazzcontainer");
    var enew = "";
    if (searchTextBox.val() != '') {
      enew = TextArea.html().replace(/(<em>|<\/em>)/igm, "");
      TextArea.html(enew);
      var query = new RegExp("(" + searchTextBox.val() + ")", "gim");
      NewText = TextArea.html().replace(query, "<em>$1</em>");
      NewText = NewText.replace(/(<em>[^<>]*)((<[^>]+>)+)([^<>]*<\/em>)/, "<em></em>");
      TextArea.html(NewText);
    } else {
      enew = TextArea.html().replace(/(<em>|<\/em>)/igm, "");
      TextArea.html(enew);
    }
  } else {

  }
});


$("#Hide_p").click(function() {
  $(".Mazzcontainer").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="Searchfield" name="q" class="form-control" required="" type="Text">
<button id="Hide_p">Click me!</button>

<p class="Mazzcontainer">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce quis lectus quis sem lacinia nonummy. Proin mollis lorem non dolor. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nulla ultrices odio. Donec augue. Phasellus dui. Maecenas facilisis nisl vitae nibh. Proin
  vel seo est vitae eros pretium dignissim. Aliquam aliquam sodales orci. Suspendisse potenti.
</p>
```

Comment: Please copy+paste your code in to the question. Images of code are useless.

Comment: 1. Is `.SomButton` a dynamically generated element? 
2. Have you tried to do a `console.log()` or `alert()` in the click event listener, to check if it's the click listener that's the problem?

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle?

Comment: The buttons are auto generated and i have not done a console.log() like that but i did do a junky function to make the console.log to say "derp" witch it didn't, 
And i can try to create a fiddle Smit

Comment: Try to do `$(".SomButton" ).on("click",function(){$(".SomList ul" ).toggle()});`

Comment: Didn't work sadly.

Comment: @SmitRaval or better a StackSnippet (click `<>` button in editor)

Comment: Also change `$("#Hide_p").click(function() {`  to `$("#Hide_p").click(function(e) { e.preventDefault();` or change the type to button

Comment: You need to wrap everything in a `$(function() { ... });` which jsfiddle and stacksnippet does for you. _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: $(function(){
 $("#Trythis").click(function(){$(".CFBU ul").toggle();});
});

Nope not even that worked. i mean is there something that i really do wrong. and the (e).preventDefault(); did allso nothing aswell. maybe it's something i've linked wrong

Comment: If it work here and not in your tests, it'll be hard to help. To solve your issue maybe try the other way around : start from a working file (code from those snippets with minimal html) and add/modify one part of code at a time to reproduce your actual test, while checking at each step if it still work.

Comment: I've taken your advice @Nomis, and i've create a simple HTML file with the same concept, And while typeing this i saw that the `<div class="Mazzcontainer">` is the one that causes the issues with the buttons. :) [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bzrthu5d/17/)

Comment: A irl friend of mine came with the selution : `$("body").on("click", ".Undertitle_1", function(){$(".Undertitle_ul_1 ul" ).toggle();}); `

Comment: Oh, that's delegation. It means that your element `.Undertitle_1` was generated after the js instruction, so it applied the `onclick` event on a non-existing element. Now with delegation (the 2nd parameter), it search the element at each click on the `body`. Glad to see you found a solution !

Comment: Ahh and i'm sorry for not explanening stuff right. :) But thanks for the inputs and stuff :D